# Actions to restore env.file in Laravel

Tags: laravel, server, environment-variables, production, mysql-error-2002

I am new in programming. I mistakenly changed my `.env` file from production server into the local `.env` file in my Laravel project.

I created a new env file, filled the data about DB, made `php artisan key:generate`,  started the commands:
`php artisan config:clear`
`php artisan route:clear`
`php artisan view:clear`
`php artisan cache:clear`
`composer dump-autoload`

But the server still shows `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused.` Maybe sommebody knows what else can I do to make the server work with the new env. Any help appreciated.

My settings changed in the new file:

`APP_ENV=production`
`APP_KEY=base64key`
`APP_DEBUG=false APP_URL=url`

`LOG_CHANNEL=stack`

`DB_CONNECTION=mysql`
`DB_HOST=host_name`
`DB_PORT=3306`
`DB_DATABASE=db name`
`DB_USERNAME=user name`
`DB_PASSWORD=password name`

Comment: this means your database connection details aren't correct

Comment: Does your password contain '#' char?

Comment: I checked db data.It's all correct.  No, password is without #.

Comment: are you using localhost? give us some info about your set-up.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem: I fixed the `.env` file correctly but mixed my new and old Git branches, so the wrong Git-Branch pulled onto the production server. Silly mistake!